# Check that a variable that has been input is between a range of two numbers, and print out a message afterwards

Tags: python

```
name = input("Hello user! What is your name?")
print("Welcome " + name + " to Rock, Scissor, Paper, Lizard, Spock!")
while True:
    try:
        roundsplayed = int(input("Choose how many rounds you want to play from 1 to 5!"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, Not a interger!")
        continue
    else:
        break
if 1 < roundsplayed < 6:
    print("You have chosen " + roundsplayed " rounds to play!")
```

So I have this, and everything seems to be working until this point.

```
if 1 < roundsplayed < 6:
print("You have chosen " + roundsplayed " rounds to play!")
```

It comes up with invalid syntax, but don't see why because the "print" command is aligned correctly (Well at least I think so)

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Your `print` is not indented correctly and you're missing a `+` sign. Also `roundsplayed` looks like it's an integer so you'll need to convert it to a string (`str(roundsplayed)`) to concatenate it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled **this code** and it works perfectly now

```
name = input("Hello user! What is your name?")
print("Welcome " + name + " to Rock, Scissor, Paper, Lizard, Spock!")
while True:
    try:
        roundsplayed = int(input("Choose how many rounds you want to play from 1 to 5!"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, Not a interger!")
        continue
    else:
        break
if 1 < roundsplayed < 6:
  print("You have chosen " + str(roundsplayed)+ " rounds to play!")
```

The problem was with the indentation in the last line and **str(roundsplayed)**. Also, you were missing **+** sign in the same line.

Comment: It fixed the interger problem, but I'm getting syntax error on the print line

Comment: @JaeMinHan check my answer now

Comment: @JaeMinHan dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate a string and a number with the + operator in python. You either need to use the , operator as -

```
print("print("You have chosen",roundsplayed,"rounds to play!")
```

Or you can convert the number to a string value -

```
 print("You have chosen " + str(roundsplayed) " rounds to play!")
```

If you use the + operator without converting the number value into string, you will get an invalid operator error.

Answer (score -1):

1. You could use the `range` function to check membership in a range of numbers. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

   ```
   >>> range(10)
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

   >>> range(2,6)
   [2, 3, 4, 5]
   ```
2. Use String formatting instead of concatenation [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). This avoids unnecessary type-casting

   ```
   name = input("Hello user! What is your name?")
   print("Welcome " + name + " to Rock, Scissor, Paper, Lizard, Spock!")
   while True:
       try:
           roundsplayed = int(input("Choose how many rounds you want to play from 1 to 5!"))
       except ValueError:
           print("Sorry, Not a interger!")
           continue
       else:
           break
   if roundsplayed in range(2, 6):
       print("You have chosen {} round to play".format(roundsplayed))
   ```

Comment: are you sure the indentation in the last statement is correct?

Comment: Yes, you could paste it into ipython and check it out :)